# Rails: Actualizar un registro desde link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito actualizar el `estado` de un registro, para ello quiero enlazarlo a un `link`, mi `código` es el siguiente:

```
<%= link_to prescription_path(pres.id), method: :patch do %>
    <i class="material-icons" style="color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54);">delete</i>
<% end %>
```

**El cual me arroja el siguiente error**
[image: resultado obtenido]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Con la información que entregas no es suficiente para saber con exactitud, pero en alguna parte de tu código estás llamando a un `require` sin pasarle parámetros, quizás en tu controlador o en el modelo. Si esto no te sirve como ayuda, entonces mejor copia/pega el error que te muestra en tu consola en vez del pantallazo, aparte agrega el código involucrado.

Comment: Problema solucionado. Gracias por la buena onda. El error estaba en uno de los permisos para ingresar a actualizar el registro